# Problem to initialize an array of structs using Defensive Programming

Tags: c

I need some help.I am trying to fill in a struct array with points of interest but I can't assign the values to the array I need to use defensive programming to make sure that the points is inside some borders. Please help.

```
struct Point_of_Interest
{
    char id[10];
    double x;
    double y;
};


struct Point_of_Interest Points[MaxPoints];

void Data_Points(struct Point_of_Interest array[])
{
    struct Point_of_Interest *p;

    int i;
    for(i=0;i<MaxPoints;i++)
    {
        do{
            printf("Give id and coordinates of the city: ");
            scanf("%s",p->id);

            printf("Dwse to X tou %d: ",i+1);
            scanf("%lf",&p->x);

            printf("Dwse to Y tou %d: ",i+1);
            scanf("%lf",&p->y);
        }while(p->x < Xmin && p->y < Ymin && p->x > Xmax && p->y > Ymax);
        array[i]=p->id,&p.x,&p.y;
    }   
}
```

inside main call

```
Data_Points(Points);
```

Comment: You need to change your condition. How could `x < xmin && x > xmax` ever be true assuming `xmin < xmax`? It's either less than minimum or more than maximum but barely both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems here.  First, the pointer `p` isn't pointer to anything.  You then attempt to dereference that pointer when assigning to each field.  Dereferencing an uninitialized pointer invoked [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Second, this isn't doing what you think:

```
array[i]=p->id,&p.x,&p.y;
```

This does not take a group of values and assign them to a struct as a unit.  It's an assignment followed by the comma operator.

The comma operator has lower precedence that the assignment operator so this expression is parsed as:

```
(array[i]=p->id),&p.x,&p.y;
```

So it's attempting to assign `p->id`, which is an array to `array[i]`, which is a type mismatch.  Then the other two values are evaluated and discarded.

You can fix these issues by declaring `p` as an instance of a `struct Point_of_Interest` instead of a pointer to one, then you can assign this whole struct to the other:

```
void Data_Points(struct Point_of_Interest array[])
{
    struct Point_of_Interest p;         // not a pointer

    int i;
    for(i=0;i<MaxPoints;i++)
    {
        do{
            // switch from -> to . wherever p is used
            printf("Give id and coordinates of the city: ");
            scanf("%s",p.id);

            printf("Dwse to X tou %d: ",i+1);
            scanf("%lf",&p.x);

            printf("Dwse to Y tou %d: ",i+1);
            scanf("%lf",&p.y);
        }while(p.x < Xmin && p.y < Ymin && p.x > Xmax && p.y > Ymax);
        array[i]=p;    // assign the whole struct
    }   
}
```